# Date Entry of SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Here I am using Oracle SQL and I have a table with 2 columns, `Keyword` and `Created_Date`.

Is there any way to get the 3rd column with information of next entry of 2nd column in accordance with first column?

Thanks guys

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output in text format, show your current attempt and describe what was wrong with it.

Comment: What do you expect to do with 3rd column. Coud you please explain clearly?

Comment: It is just an example. I may not need just date, i might need other options. I might see if is there any sale before that entry etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `LEAD` analytic function. Sample data in lines #1 - 10; query begins at line #11.

```
SQL> with test (keyword, datum) as
  2    (select 'A', date '2021-01-18' from dual union all
  3     select 'A', date '2021-04-26' from dual union all
  4     select 'B', date '2021-03-01' from dual union all
  5     select 'B', date '2021-04-26' from dual union all
  6     select 'B', date '2021-03-01' from dual union all
  7     select 'C', date '2021-02-24' from dual union all
  8     select 'C', date '2021-02-24' from dual union all
  9     select 'C', date '2021-08-04' from dual
 10    )
 11  select keyword,
 12         datum,
 13         lead(datum) over (order by keyword, datum) next_entry_date
 14  from test
 15  order by keyword, datum;

KEYWORD  DATUM      NEXT_ENTRY
-------- ---------- ----------
A        18.01.2021 26.04.2021
A        26.04.2021 01.03.2021
B        01.03.2021 01.03.2021
B        01.03.2021 26.04.2021
B        26.04.2021 24.02.2021
C        24.02.2021 24.02.2021
C        24.02.2021 04.08.2021
C        04.08.2021

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```